# RSpec Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using Rails 6 with Grape and I don't know why my specs without any reason began to return such an error

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/health_check_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage:
  ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
```

Which is super weird because I had no such problem before. I add `devise` and `shoulda-matchers gem` but even without these gems I'm getting the same error.

spec_helper:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.default_formatter = 'doc' if config.files_to_run.one?

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
  config.profile_examples = 10
  config.order = :random

  Kernel.srand config.seed
end
```

rails_helper:

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!') if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'

begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

Comment: This error seems to be related to your secrets.yml.enc. Did you update the key lately? Or, move to a different computer without the key or with a different key?

Comment: I started getting this same error randomly once I upgraded MacOS to Big Sur.